# How to Store the Fields of Collection Objects in MySql Database

Tags: mysql, struts2

I am using Struts2 framework and tiles feature for creating a web application. In that, there is a page where i provide input text fields for getting information of blood groups and also there is a functionality to add dynamic rows for adding more data at a time using javascript. On click the save button , the value entered in all  the row  are collected in the Action Class using Collection object by using getters and setters.

Now the problem is , how to store the submitted values of blood group objects in the database.
Please help me to store the values in the database .

Comment: how you storing it in database? are you using any ORM solution like hibernate or JPA and this is more like a issue or persistence layer not S2

Comment: Thanks. I dont know more about Hibernate or JPA. Could you please provide some details and an sample link which demonstrate the process of how to store it .

Comment: refer to this more more details http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-tutorial/hibernate-tutorial.html. I suggest you to go with any ORM solution which will help you to work with database more easily

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try your suggestion.Thanks a lot